# Defining an array of structures in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

main.h

```
#define  DATA  struct   data
DATA
{
  int id;
  char data;
}
```

main.c

```
DATA *listOfData[100];
```

So at this point I will/should be able to access DATA in the list like this:

```
printf(listOfData[5]->data);
```

It isn't letting me do it, the run just freezes on that last print f...no error or anything.

Comment: Don't hide keywords behind #defines. You confuse yourself.

Comment: The defines are part of the framework/pseudo code my prof gave me

Comment: Well: tell him to stop doing that!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have defined an array of pointers. But you never initialized any of the pointers.

Therefore:

```
printf(listOfData[5]->data);
```

will crash (undefined behavior) because you are dereferencing the (invalid) pointer at index 5.

*(And that's a very odd way to define a struct...)

To fix this issue, you will need to allocate for each of the pointers in the array. If you don't actually need it to be an array of pointers, then it might be better to just make it array of the struct itself:

```
DATA listOfData[100];
```

and access it as:

```
listOfData[5].data
```

Then you don't have to deal with allocating each element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `printf` would just freeze, but there's a couple of things wrong with this. First, all the pointers in your `DATA*` array are uninitialized. You probably intended to make an array of `DATA`, instead of an array of `DATA` pointers:

```
DATA listOfData[100];
```

You also didn't end the struct with a semicolon, so it seems unlikely that this would even compile:

```
#define  DATA  struct   data
DATA
{
  int id;
  char data;
};
```

Finally, you're using `printf` in a rather unsafe way; the first argument needs to be a format string, or you can get weird behavior if the first argument has a `%` in it:

```
printf("%c\n", listOfData[5].data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any memory allocation for the DATA *. Either declare your array as an array of struct data, like:

```
DATA listOfData[100];
```

or allocate memory dynamically and assign the pointers in your array.