# Creating an array of structures in C?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining an array of structures in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113442/defining-an-array-of-structures-in-c)

I have a structure DATA which has two fields (int - id and char - dat).

I allocate memory to it:

```
DATA *current = malloc(sizeof(DATA));
```

And assign all the fields:

```
current->id = 1;
current->dat = a;
```

What I am not sure how to do...is how to add the DATA I just initialized into an array of DATA (which is declared as DATA lstData[100])

---

Also, from asking previous questions, I feel like maybe I don't need to malloc in this case since I have a static array of 100 DATA elements? In that case, the following code fails:

```
lstProc[10]->id = 1; //Error: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
```

Comment: This question is to similar (and even has the same title) to your previous one. You should edit and clean that question up instead of creating a new one from scratch

Comment: Could you please post your array initialisation?
because which operator to use (-> or .) is dependent on if you are defining an array for pointers to your DATA Struct or directly an Array on you Data Struct.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. No need to malloc. Since you have an array of structures (not pointers to structures), use:

```
lstProc[10].id = 1;
```

Comment: To make the array global I would define it in the header file as DATA lstData[0] and then once again, in the main, when I actually have the size known (from user input), define it there? DATA lstData[inpputSize]

Answer (score 1):

If you have static array of DATA structures, NOT of pointers to DATA, you need to use dot to access particular DATA members:

```
lstProc[10].id = 1;
```

And answer to your original question:

```
memcpy(&(lstProc[10]), current, sizeof(DATA));
```